# Android October Security Patch 2019 broke my app

Tags: android, cordova, crash

My team noticed that after upgrading our QA devices with the October 2019 Security Patch (primarily Samsung and Pixel phone devices), our app is no longer stable.

We are seeing crashes due to a signal 9 in adb logs:

```
11-01 09:23:51.067   832   832 I Zygote  : Process 24758 exited due to signal 9 (Killed)
```

These crashes are not showing up in our Crashlytics reporting, but we are seeing evidence of this crash via metrics (Session length) and reviews (up tick in 1 star reviews indicating instability).

We cannot find any one thing that triggers this crash.  Sitting on our home screen for 5 or so minutes will result in a crash.  Navigating around the app for 5 or so minutes will result in a crash.

I've seen some reports indicating signal 9 is tied to memory, but profiling our app shows a stable memory profile, and if anything, we've seen memory slightly decreasing leading to the crash.

Our app is a Cordova app with a sizeable native plugin foot print.

```
Cordova: 7.0.0 (also tried upgrading to 8.1.0 to no avail)
DJI SDK: 4.11
Google Maps: 16.0.0
RxJava: 2.2.3
Support Libs: AndroidX
```

Has anyone else experienced instability with this latest update?  Tips on debugging this Signal 9 crash?

Thanks.

11/20/2019 Update:

Android OS:

```
Android 9
Android 10
```

We've tried removing the DJI SDK entirely from the application and the app is still crashing.

Comment: You might want to include OS versions on devices you are encountering the problem (probably Android 9 & Android 10 but just to make sure).

Comment: Also any issue with the DJI SDK (a complicated third party component) sample app on problem devices?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I doubt DJI SDK is the problem.  We've looked into other DJI based apps and they are not crashing, so it's unlikely DJI is the culprit.  I also have a sample app using Cordova and Google Maps that is not crashing.  We *think* we have found a range of commits from a year ago that behave nice with this Android Update, but the nature of this crash is making it hard to pin point and find a subset of changes that introduce this problem.